# AND & OR condition in elasticsearch API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have address with address component stored in my elasticSearch, each address looks like following in my ES :

```
 {
                 "_index": "properties",
                 "_type": "_doc",
                 "_id": "property_5235354",
                 "_score": 32.839436,
                 "_source": {
                     "id": 5235354,
                     "branchid": 1,
                     "suburb": "Lyons",
                     "postcode": "2606",
                     "state": "ACT",
                     "@timestamp": "2021-09-27T08:56:08.827Z",
                     "agencycode": "X",
                     "address": "54-5 Burnie St Lyons ACT 2606 AUS",
                     "streetnumber": "5",
                     "branchcode": "X_ACT",
                     "unitnumber": "54",
                     "agencyid": 1,
                     "streetname": "Burnie St",
                     "@version": "1"
                 }
}
```

To search specific address on the basis of components I am considering following points :

1. There could be abbreviation of street names like "James Street" -> "James St"
2. Matching by address components with exact match in case insensitive manner
3. Please let me know if you think I should consider something else

To do this I tried following :

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "streetname.keyword": "Burnie Street"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "streetname.keyword": "Burnie St"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "unitnumber.keyword": "54"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "streetnumber.keyword": "5"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "suburb.keyword": "Lyons"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "state": "ACT"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "postcode.keyword": "2606"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 1000
}
```

Need your help on solving these :

1. Above query is also returning invalid result like address : `54-5 Burnie Avenue Lyons ACT 2606 AUS` which is Burnie Avenue not Burnie Street.
2. If I give `burnie street` instead of `Burnie Street`, its unable to find the data.

More information :
This is the full result of _search API with above request body where addresses `54-5 Burnie St Lyons ACT 2606 AUS` & `54/5 Burnie Street Lyons ACT 2606` are right match but `54-5 Burnie Avenue Lyons ACT 2606 AUS` is an **invalid match**

```
{
    "took": 1476,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 32.839436,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "properties",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "property_5235354",
                "_score": 32.839436,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 5235354,
                    "branchid": 1,
                    "suburb": "Lyons",
                    "postcode": "2606",
                    "state": "ACT",
                    "@timestamp": "2021-09-27T08:56:08.827Z",
                    "agencycode": "X",
                    "address": "54-5 Burnie St Lyons ACT 2606 AUS",
                    "streetnumber": "5",
                    "branchcode": "X_ACT",
                    "unitnumber": "54",
                    "agencyid": 1,
                    "streetname": "Burnie St",
                    "@version": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "properties",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "property_11081",
                "_score": 28.954222,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 11081,
                    "branchid": 1,
                    "suburb": "Lyons",
                    "postcode": "2606",
                    "state": "ACT",
                    "@timestamp": "2021-09-27T08:56:08.163Z",
                    "agencycode": "X",
                    "address": "54/5 Burnie Street Lyons ACT 2606",
                    "streetnumber": "5",
                    "branchcode": "X_ACT",
                    "unitnumber": "54",
                    "agencyid": 1,
                    "streetname": "Burnie Street",
                    "@version": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "properties",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "property_5235356",
                "_score": 22.677355,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 5235356,
                    "branchid": 1,
                    "suburb": "Lyons",
                    "postcode": "2606",
                    "state": "ACT",
                    "@timestamp": "2021-09-27T08:56:08.847Z",
                    "agencycode": "X",
                    "address": "54-5 Burnie Avenue Lyons ACT 2606 AUS",
                    "streetnumber": "5",
                    "branchcode": "X_ACT",
                    "unitnumber": "54",
                    "agencyid": 1,
                    "streetname": "Burnie Avenue",
                    "@version": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: if it helps same query in SQL would be : 
select * from properties p where streetnumber = '5' and unitnumber = '54' and (streetname = 'Burnie Street' or streetname = 'Burnie St')
and suburb = 'Lyons' and postcode = '2606' and state = 'ACT'

Comment: just a quick note that it's Elasticsearch, not elasticSearch :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `bool/must/should` query clause, [term](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query (for exact match ignoring the case), and [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) query

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "agencycode": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "agencyid": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "branchcode": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "branchid": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "postcode": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "state": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "streetname": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "streetnumber": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "suburb": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "unitnumber": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "streetnumber": "5"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "unitnumber": "54"
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "streetname.keyword": {
                    "value": "Burnie Street",
                    "case_insensitive": "true"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "streetname": "Burnie St"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "suburb.keyword": {
              "value": "Lyons",
              "case_insensitive": "true"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "postcode.keyword": "2606"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "state.keyword": {
              "value": "ACT",
              "case_insensitive": "true"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Prakhar Verma please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: working like a charm, will test on it more. You're the real ES Ninja. TYSM

Comment: @PrakharVerma glad I could help you, and thanks for your kind words ;-)